# How can I get back the password I stored in a JCEKS keystore?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, jceks

I have created a keystore using the java keytool to store a passowrd using the following command

```
$ keytool -importpassword -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.jceks -storetype jceks 
Enter keystore password:  keystore
Re-enter new password: keystore
Enter the password to be stored: testpassword 
Re-enter password: testpassword
Enter key password for <myalias>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

I want to retrieve this password in a java program. Here's what I have written so far.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("mykeystore.jceks"));
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
ks.load(is, "keystore".toCharArray());
PasswordProtection pp = new PasswordProtection("keystore".toCharArray());
SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("myalias", pp);
System.out.println(ske.toString()); // Outputs: "Secret key entry with algorithm PBEWithMD5AndDES"
```

How can I get back the password I store? Is it even possible?

Complete reference code below.

Required libraries:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection;
import java.security.KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
```

Class:

```
class JCEKS 
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        try{
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("mykeystore.jceks"));
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
            ks.load(is, "keystore".toCharArray());
            PasswordProtection pp = new PasswordProtection("keystore".toCharArray());
            SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("myalias", pp);

            System.out.println(ske.toString());
        }
        catch(KeyStoreException e){
            System.out.println("KeyStoreException:");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(CertificateException e){
            System.out.println("CertificateException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(UnrecoverableKeyException e){
            System.out.println("UnrecoverableKeyException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(UnrecoverableEntryException e){
            System.out.println("UnrecoverableEntryException:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can't. It is hashed, not encrypted. You didn't store the password in the KeyStore, you created the KeyStore with the password. It isn't inside there in an entry. If you forgot it, bad luck.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that clarification. No I didn't forget the password. I was under the impression that when I was prompted to enter a password to be stored, the password would be stored somewhere and I would be able to retrieve it if i provided the keystore password.

Comment: To clarify: essentially what I am expecting (hoping) to get back is that "testpassword" phrase.

Comment: Your impression would violate all known concepts of security. Life isn't like that, and it shouldn't be. A recoverable password is no security at all.

Comment: The OP was referring to the password entry that can be store as secret key entry [-importpassword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_importpassword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and some trial and error, it turns out you CAN retrieve a password that you store using keytool
For example, if you use the following command to store a password

```
    > $ keytool -importpassword -alias my-alias -keystore my-keystore.jcek -storetype jceks

    > Enter keystore password:  keystorepassword 
    > Re-enter new password:keystorepassword 
    > Enter the password to be stored: thepassword
    > Re-enter password: thepassword 
    > Enter key password for <my-alias>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password): keypassword 
    > Re-enter new password: keypassword
```

To retrieve the password your stored (i.e. 'thepassword'):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("my-keystore.jceks"));
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks.load(is, "keystorepassword".toCharArray());
PasswordProtection pp = new PasswordProtection("keypassword".toCharArray());
SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("my-alias", pp);
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec) factory.getKeySpec(ske.getSecretKey(), PBEKeySpec.class);
String password = new String(keySpec.getPassword());
System.out.println(password);
```

Output: thepassword

Note that when you store a string, it defaults to *PBEWITHMD5ANDDES* algorithm. So you will need to download the **javax-crypto.jar** and compile it along with your program `javac -cp javax-crypto.jar your-program.java`

Answer (score 1):

The `password` entry you stored is stored as a `SecretKeyEntry` and its value can be retrieved using the `getEncoded()` method of the `secretKey` object.

> System.out.println(new String(ske.getSecretKey().getEncoded()));